# How to make link-notes that that direct send you to the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I wrote my blybliography like this :

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
 \bibitem{notes} Reviews of Modern Physics , VOLUME 88 : {\em  
   Active Particles in Complex and Crowded Environments} ,  2016.
 \end{thebibliography}
```

how I can make a note that if you click on it send you to right referecne of the biblio?

footnote allows you just to link at the end of the page...

Comment: If you load `hyperref` `\cite{notes}` should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
 \usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
```